# I want a wpf application to detect usb or cd drive when i inserted

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0

I have created wpf application with listbox having some images. Now what i want is if i inserted usb or cd into the system having some images my application has to start automatically once i inserted usb or cd having images and application has to ask whether to add those images of usb or cd to the application by default.

Any source code plz... any suggestions also...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You could investigate:

1. [SharpUSBLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpUSBLib/default.aspx)
2. [A USB HID Component for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/USB_HID.aspx)
3. [Detect CD-ROM Insertion](http://en.csharp-online.net/Detect_CD-ROM_Insertion)
4. [How to detect a CD Drive in C#?](http://www.discussweb.com/c-programming/4201-how-detect-cd-drive-c.html)